# How to call on json based API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

Im trying to call on a json based authentication API, but its not working. The API takes two parameters as input in JSON format; username and password.

What am I doing wrong? here is my current test code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>API test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>API test</h1>
        <button id="btn">test</button>
    </header>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script>
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function () {
            const serverResponse = document.getElementById("result");
            serverResponse.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

        xhr.open("POST", "url");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.send("username=test&password=test");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your API expects json but you’re sending it form data. Look up how to post json.

Comment: `in JSON format` but `"username=test&password=test"` is not JSON.

Comment: my bad. Does this look better? it still does not work. const input = [{
            "username": "test",
            "password": "test."
        }];
xhr.send(input);

Comment: That `input` is an array, not JSON. JSON is a string representation of an array or object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
xhr.open("POST", "url");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ username: "test", password: "test" }));
```

Comment: I keep getting this error message in the console window in the browser:
Failed to load "URL": Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I think you are calling a different domain URL other than your domain and that domain is protected by cross domain access check.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The server and the workstation is under the same domain. Could it be a firewall on the server that is blocking the access?

Comment: Enable CORS in PHP using header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");